# What is the flowering bush called

Tags: identification

[image]
This is a Bush with Orange flowers [image]

Comment: what part of the world are you in?

Answer (score 1):

This could be Honeysuckle...Lonicera sempervirens
[image: Honey suckle, Capensis]

Check out the serrated margins...?  Odd pinnate?

Comment: I don't know what species are called "honeysuckle" in the USA, but it doesn't look like any *Lonicera* I have ever seen, in either colour or shape.

Comment: Hey first impressions get dialogue jumpin' donchathink?  Grins!  What do you think this guy is?  Amazing we are supposed to ID stuff with credibility from a photo.  Bamboo and you as well, somehow got used to IDing using photos,  truly remarkable.  It is all good, Alephzero...honest!

Answer (score 1):

When you say bush, it would be good to know how big it actually is overall, but I strongly suspect it's a Campsis https://www.123rf.com/photo_94779892_trumpet-shaped-orange-flowers-of-campsis-radicans.html variety. It's a vine or climber, but will grow as a sort of rather untidy heap with orange flowers if it does not have a support to climb up.

Comment: Thank you.  I clicked on your link and that was the flowering bush I have in my yard.

Comment: I call it "trumpet vine" , it is invasive in east TX. It doesn't bother me ,but I understand many are allergic to touching it. It will easily go up over 50 ft.